# Can't get C3PO to work with Spring+JPA+Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-java-config

I'm trying to configure C3PO in my Spring + Hibernate application (Java configurations) using a JPA Transaction manager but can't get it to work. The following is my HibernateConfig class. Please help!

PS: Initially, I had configured my HibernateConfig class to use the HibernateTransactionManager and I was successfully able to configure C3PO with it, but when I switched to using the JPA transaction manager and the EntityManagerFactory, setting the C3PO properties doesn't do anything at all. I tried setting the C3PO properties using both the nativ C3PO keys as well as the Hibernate version of the keys, but to no avail.

```
package com.company.core.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"com.company.core.data"})
public class EntityManagerFactoryConfiguration {
    public EntityManagerFactoryConfiguration() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.company.core.data.pojos"});

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "100");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "0");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment", "1");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "200");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "0");
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "300");
        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/databasename?autoReconnect=true");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource c3p0dataSource() {
        final com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/databasename?autoReconnect=true");
        dataSource.setUser("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
```

Comment: You have two `DataSource` beans in the configuration and you are not using the C3P0 `DataSource` anywhere. You should have `em.setDataSource(c3p0dataSource())` instead of ``em.setDataSource(dataSource())` if you want the `EntityManager` to use the C3P0 `DataSource`.

Comment: @manish ,I have tried using the C3PO data source but wasn't able to establish a connection with my database with it. Which is why I switched back to the Spring datasource. With the Spring datasource, I can successfully connect to my database with the exact same jdbc url and credentials.

Comment: Please modify the question to reflect the exact configuration that is failing, otherwise, it is confusing because others don't know what is not working. It is also unclear what is meant by `setting the C3PO properties doesn't do anything at all`. Is there an error (if yes, please add that as well). The question should include supporting facts, such as, what steps were followed that led to the said conclusion, etc. Right now the question is a debugging problem that only you can solve because there isn't enough information for others to comment.